# How to shuffle all songs in iOS 8.4 music app

Tags: ios, music.app

In the old version of the music app you could shuffle all songs when songs were selected:

[image]  [image]

This feature seems to be absent in iOS 8.4 and the new music app:

[image]

---

## What are the options for shuffling all my songs in the new version of the music app under iOS 8.4?

Comment: Although there are workarounds, this is clearly another Apple design flaw. Submit feedback to Apple here: https://feedback.apple.com/ and/or submit a bug report here: https://bugreport.apple.com   See no reason why they should make shuffling music so complicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- In the My Music tab under the `Recently Added` album artwork is a title which by default reads `Artists` it is a pink drop down menu.
- Select `Songs` from the list.
- Select any song to start playback.
- Enable shuffle mode, disable repeat.

Comment: @deeksbek did this answer your question?

Comment: "Enable shuffle mode" isn't specific enough!  James Berry's answer says how to do it.

Comment: @RandyOrrison There is an icon which is the shuffle icon, you press that. Also James Berrys's answer doesn't necessarily shuffle all songs if you are in a playlist, album or other grouping of music. James Copelands is better but requires a compatible device. Glad you found a solution that works for you however.

Answer (score 5):

The above solutions didn't work for me. What worked for me was after starting a song, I tapped the bottom bar that shows what's playing. Upon tapping, a window with the album cover appears along with the player controls, including the shuffle and repeat buttons.

Comment: Based on what you asked my solution and the others would work, if you are using iOS 8.4 then it will work.

Comment: @janaspage - did you start from "Songs" or Artist?  I think if you start from a song in Songs, it will shuffle through all, but if you start from a song in the Artist list, it will shuffle that artist. Likewise if you start from a song in an Album, it will shuffle that album. But I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 4):

To shuffle all music select Artists, Albums, or Songs, press play on the ear buds

In other modes of play the shuffle is a toggle. It will remember if its on or off. If its on pressing the picture in the Artists list will play all their music shuffled. If shuffle is off it will play all music starting with the most recent album in album order.

The same is true with the Album list. Shuffle on, press the picture, the songs of that album are shuffled. Shuffle off, songs play in album order.

Comment: Kind of crap if you're not using Apple's earbuds.

Comment: And doesn't work if there is no photo of the artists - missing from some artists.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Music app, scrolled to the top]

Scroll further up the front page of the music app, and there is a "Shuffle All" command hidden there.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the command "shuffle music" with siri

Comment: @janaspage  if you have a headset you can do it in a public noisy place.

Comment: For me, if you say "Shuffle music" Siri just says "OK turning shuffle on" but doesn't play music. Then you have to say "Play music" to actually play anything,