# iOS 8.4 Apple Music App: How to shuffle all songs by an artist?

Tags: ios, music.app, apple-music

With the complete redesign featuring the new streaming mixin (which I don't use), it seems that when listening to music from my library (stored on my device) I can only shuffle songs within a single album for an artist.

This is not a dupe of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194294/how-to-shuffle-all-songs-in-ios-8-4-music-app), in that I'm not asking how to shuffle all songs in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of selecting the artist to display the albums and songs of the artist, tap the image of the artist and the artists songs will play shuffled.

Comment: They will only play shuffled if it was already activated.

Answer (score 3):

Answer: Siri > Play " artist " songs shuffle

Answer (score 2):

These seem to be the current ways to shuffle in the new 8.4 Music.app: [About.com "How to Shuffle Music on the iPhone" - Updated 7/8/2015](http://ipod.about.com/od/iPhoneMusicApp/ss/Iphone-Music-App-Shuffling-Songs.htm)

> **Shuffle All Songs**
>
> To shuffle all the songs in your Music app library, which will give
>   you the greatest variety and a roughly random order of songs, follow
>   these easy steps:
>
> 1. Open the Music app
> 2. Tap My Music
> 3. Make sure the menu just below Apple Music is set to Songs
> 4. Find a song you'd like to listen to and tap it to begin it playing
> 5. Tap the playback bar just above the buttons at the bottom of the
>      screen to reveal the album art and full set of Music app controls
> 6. At the bottom of the screen, tap the Shuffle button, which is two arrows crossing over each other. You'll know it's enabled when it's
>      highlighted.
>
> With that done, your next song will be randomly chosen and you're off
>   on a shuffling adventure. Use the forward arrow to skip to the next
>   song or the back arrow to return to the last one.
>
> ​To turn off shuffle, just tap the two-arrow icon again so it is no
>   longer highlighted.

Comment: Context added and quoted.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect method, absent an actual shuffle button on the artist's page, that works for me:

1. Tap For You at the bottom of the app
2. Tap Apple Music at the top
3. Search for an artist
4. In the search results, tap on Songs
5. Tap on a song to begin playing
6. Tap the banner at the bottom for the currently playing song
7. Tap the shuffle button

You'll now be listening to a shuffle of all songs by that artist.  Definitely less convenient, but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I realize what I did wrong and updated the steps.  I also changed the steps to a numbered list.  Note that the search-based approach is not without a margin of error.  It's possible that searching for oft-covered artists like "The Beatles" will return non-Beatles versions of songs.

Answer (score 0):

- Tap My Music
- If it doesn't say "Artists" in red under the recently added section, tap the label and select **Artists**
- Now select the artist you want to shuffle
- If they have one album, the shuffle button is there in front of you
- **If they have multiple albums, tap the three dot icon (...) to the right of the share button (the square with the up arrow).**
- Tap "Play Next"
- use the control center or other method to skip to the next song

To confirm that you added all the songs you want, click the now playing banner and click the "menu" icon to the right of the "next song" arrows, this will bring up all the songs that are up next.

If that's too lengthy, you can use Siri to play songs by an artist - one tap to accomplish.

> Siri play songs by U2 shuffle

You can also make a playlist with the artists you desire and play those by tapping or by voice control.

Comment: Good thing there are two options @janaspage :-)

Comment: @janaspage Intuitive is a matter of practice, expectation and opinion. Apple is famous (some say notorious) for cutting visual clutter and the old option clearly saw the cutting room floor instead of shipping. I think embracing siri if you can will free you from UI changes and obsolete (for many or most) edge cases like this one. Also, you don't have to manage the queue. Just stop listening or queue up new songs.

Answer (score 0):

NOT IMPOSSIBLE to shuffle all your music unless you have an Internet connection.  (i.e.  It IS possible to shuffle all songs, though it's not exactly intuitive.)

Procedure:

1) Open music app.
2) Open My Music (left button at bottom of screen).
3) Press Songs in middle of screen (in list of Artists, Albums, etc.)  You may need to scroll to top of page.
4) Press album cover icon at far left of any song in the list.
5) Press "now playing" bar near bottom of screen (directly above My Music, Playlists, Radio, etc.) at very bottom of screen.  Album cover and full transport controls will appear.
6) Press shuffle button at bottom left/center of screen (below horizontal volume bar).
7) Press Next transport button (on right side of Play button).  All songs in phone will play in random (shuffled) order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use alternative players I found this app on the App Store called [Ecoute](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/ecoute-starker-musik-player/id536882653?mt=8).  It seamlessly works with your iTunes music library and you can shuffle on artist, genre and more.  It is a basic, easy and intuitive player...

"[image]

Comment: Ecoute seems to be an app for iOS (it appears to have had an OS X version on the past). Anyway, this does not answer the OP, it offers a general alternative but not a solution to the specific question asked.

Comment: From my point of view, the answer *does* offer a solution to the problem described by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

FOund this in another forum, by another person and it works:

Go into your music, type the artists name in the search bar and make sure that 'my music' is selected. then the artist will come up, their albums will come up, then their songs will come up. Click on songs and once you play one you can press shuffle and it will shuffle all of the songs from that artist.

Answer (score 0):

As with many of the other responses, I have found the easiest method for shuffling all songs for an artist with multiple albums:

-My Music
-Make sure Artists is selected
-Scroll to your artist
-Tap the icon to the left of the name of the artist - this will usually be a thumbnail graphic of an album cover
-Tap the song bar towards the bottom of the screen
-Tap the "shuffle" icon at the bottom - this will look like two crossing arrows

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to shuffle all your music unless you have an internet connection, which is the most ridiculous thing in a long line of bad design moves from Apple.

I've moved across to this free app https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/musis-a-simple-music-player/id849003298?mt=8
which works very nicely with your existing music library, has very intuitive controls, shuffles, and no it's not in Korean despite the screenshots!

Answer (score -2):

tell Siri to play my music on shuffle.