# How to shuffle all songs by an artist in macOS iTunes?

Tags: itunes

It seems like I can only shuffle songs within a single album for an artist. I want to shuffle all the songs from 1 artist.

[Found this question abou shuffling songs on iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195751/ios-8-4-apple-music-app-how-to-shuffle-all-songs-by-an-artist), but I have the same question for iTunes in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

How about: 1) create a smart playlist matching the artist name; 2) select the playlist; 3) hit shuffle.  Just a thought.